# Excel PivotTable result vs executed MDX query result

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, mdx, powerpivot

I am executing an MDX query retrieved from Excel PivotTable connected to an OLAP Cube in SQL Server Management Studio. I have retrieved the MDX query using SQL Profiler while refreshing it in Excel.

I am just dragging in one dimension attribute in the PivotTable's "Rows" box. Excel shows me all customer Ids putting them one for each row (like a simple select in T-SQL would do). That matches what I was expecting.

I noticed that while Excel shows the selected dimension attribute on Rows, using the retrieved MDX query in the management studio shows it on Columns.

The MDX query I get from SQL Profiler is:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize (
 {
  DrilldownLevel (
   { [CustomerDimension].[CustomerId].[All] }
   ,
   ,
   , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
  )
 }
) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS
FROM [DWH] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, LANGUAGE
, BACK_COLOR
, FORE_COLOR
, FONT_FLAGS
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: if you reconfigure the pivot table and actually put the names on the columns does the mdx stay the same?

Comment: Hi, yes the query does not change. It is like Excel make some sort of post processing....just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not ask for more than one `Axis`. And `COLUMNS` is the **Alias** for Axis(**0**). For you, it might be easier to read data in a "Rows" display look. For excel what matters is the information on each Axis.

I would like to add an extra info to help you in your MDX exploration.

[Olap PivotTable Extension](https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/)

*I'm in no way affiliated with this extension, but it is really usefull.*

EDIT:

You can set your axis(0) as an empty SET `{ }` and display your Customers in the `ROWS`Axis.

```
SELECT
    { } on 0,
    [CustomerDimension].[CustomerId].[All].CHILDREN ON 1
FROM [DWH]
```

Comment: Yes Excel happens to use the columns axis for pivots which just have fields on rows. As soon as you put a different field on columns in the PivotTable then the underlying MDX query will look more like you are expecting when run in SSMS.

Comment: thanks for your answer. You are correctly speaking in terms of general MDX sintax and I know you are right. My problem is related to Excel behaviour rather then how to change MDX to get what I am expecting. My problem is to make the end user able to extract the MDX and paste it into a software we are designing. I am already using the extension you pointed at so the user can extract it. I am just trying to get the same result with the MDX as excel shows. @GregGalloway: thanks. It is a possible workaround but I am trying to understand what's behind the scene :)

Comment: @GiulioV. Excel uses sub-selects a lot - I'd never write mdx in that style - it also adds in lots of boilerplate cell property fluff. It's definitely the most available but might not be the best reference for mdx.